# C++ Output Window Won't Take Keyboard Input

Tags: c++, keyboard, output

I am trying to make a bot play Super Mario World and I downloaded an emulator to test on. I have a basic setup to output keyboard events, but it only works to write text and the game doesn't, or any other window for that matter, pick up the events. The output looks like this "cccccccccc". This is the raw output of the program. Any ideas on why it only writes text and wont trigger real keyboard strokes? Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the code I am working with.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <string>

// Virtual key press handler
void pressKey(string key, INPUT vir){
    char temp = key[0];
    vir.ki.wScan = temp;
    SendInput(1, &vir, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main(){
    // Initialize the virtual keyboard.
    INPUT vir;
    vir.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    vir.ki.time = 0;
    vir.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    vir.ki.wVk = 0;
    vir.ki.wScan = 0;
    vir.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Sleep for 5 seconds then jump every second for 10 jumps.
    Sleep(5000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pressKey("c", vir);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: It's a win32 console application that I run and click on the window that I want it to run keyboard events on.

Comment: Assuming the emulator is reading from stdin, you need to pipe the output from your bot to the emulator i.e.